# Does an XML parser exists in Objective C without knowing the tags' names?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml-parsing

I am looking for a tutorial or example of a kind of "universal parser" for XML for iPhone development. I don't know if it is possible, but I would like to find one that can parse every XML file without knowing the name of the tags (fields?) inside the < >  symbols. 
Does anyone knows if it's possible?

Maybe I'm not using the right vocabulary, I hope you understood, sorry for my english!

Comment: of course you could parse without knowing the tag names or better without behaving different dependent on the elements names. You'd end up with an object structure representing the XML structure 1:1. Is this really what you want?

Comment: There is something wrong with XML structure 1.1?

Comment: No, I ment 1:1 like one to one. Let's say you got <first att1="one"><second att2="2"></second></first> then your universal parser would create objects of class `XMLElement` containing  arrays `childElements` and `attributes` which would be exact copy of the xml into objects. But typically you would want an object of class `First` containing a typed member `att1` and a member `sec` of class `Second` and so on. See the difference? For the latter approach you could write an universal parser with reflection, but it's easier to build some knowledge of the object structure into the parser.

Comment: Why not simply use a document-based parser and scan the nodes as you need?

Comment: Hmmmmm using the class `First` seems better, but actually I am a real beginner in Objective C. That's why I hoped to find a example of code that I can use in my code, I find it easier to understand how it works by manipulating fragments of code!

Comment: I found exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for your advices!
[link](http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/parsing-xml-files/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a static library that serves this purpose of XML Parsing without any knowledge of tag names.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11077584/XMLParser_lazyWorkaholics.zip

Please go through this post for further reference

http://ioslazyworks.blogspot.in/2013/05/ios-universal-xml-parser.html